# Limit eager loaded comments

Tags: php, sql, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I want to load all my news with comments. Right now, I am retrieving all news with all comments. However, I only want 2 comments to be shown to each news item.

`$news = News::with('user')->with('comments.user')->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->get();`

How do I get only 2 comments out with each news item?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if that's possible.

You can do something like this:

```
News::with(array('comments.user' => function($q) { $q->take(2); }));
```

But it will take two comments from the entire set (genereated query will look like `SELECT * FROM users WHERE id IN (...) LIMIT 2`).

I had the same problem. I've done it in a dirty way - iterate over News records, fetch to them two comments and cache the whole thing.

Comment: Using this method it will only grab 2 comments for the whole page :-P I guess I'm going to have to count the comments and only pick the newest two

Comment: @radmen can you show me shortly how you was doing in your that dirty way ?